# case insensitive parameter binding in minimal api and swagger dokumentation

Tags: c#, webapi, .net-8.0

I have a c# .net 8 minimal api witch takes as a parameter an enum:

```
app.MapGet("/{id}/attachments/{category}/{attachmentId}", async (
            Guid id,
            AttachmentCategory category,
            string attachmentId) => {
                ...
            })
```

Enum:

```
public enum AttachmentCategory
{
    Documents,
    Photos
}
```

I am using `System.Text.Json`

Serialization:

```
options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase));
```

works:

```
https://localhost:1234/api/v1/item/b9c10df0-c974-4876-a3fa-d4b5e8140929/attachments/Documents/3abd9b3b-97e9-4668-b4b3-50cbcdac0220.pdf
```

does not work:

```
https://localhost:1234/api/v1/item/b9c10df0-c974-4876-a3fa-d4b5e8140929/attachments/documents/3abd9b3b-97e9-4668-b4b3-50cbcdac0220.pdf
```

Can I make lower case work? mybe both?

Problem 2:
The enum parameter shows up in swagger as a string not as an enum

Is a `IDocumentFilter` the only way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix problem2,you may try:

```
builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter());
});
builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter());
});
```

.....

```
app.MapGet("/{id}/attachments/{category}/{attachmentId}", (
            Guid id,
            [FromRoute] AttachmentCategory category,
            string attachmentId) =>
{
    .....
})
.WithOpenApi();
```

[image]

To fix problem 1:

```
app.MapGet("/{id}/attachments/{category}/{attachmentId}", (Guid id, [FromRoute]Category category, string attachmentId) =>
{
    return attachmentId;
})
.WithOpenApi();

public class Category
{
    [FromRoute]
    public AttachmentCategory category { get; set; }

    public static bool TryParse(string? value, IFormatProvider? provider,
                                out Category? categoryval)
    {

       
        
        var success= Enum.TryParse<AttachmentCategory>(value,
                                    ignoreCase: true, out var categoryenumval);
        if(success)
        {
            categoryval = new Category() { category = categoryenumval };
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            categoryval = null;
            return false;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

accroding to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/parameter-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#tryparse),related [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45590) on github

but in this senaro,you need a filter to relapce category schema(if you need ,i will deliever it to you tomorrow)
[image]